# Album Folder Rename not working in Android 11

Tags: android, file, rename, mediastore

I have an issue while renaming albums in Android 11. I have tried with `createWriteRequest` also. But Failed to rename that folder Albums. Any one please guide me on this.

First I select folder "ABC" and want to rename it to "XYZ".

so, normally I do like this;

```
File mainFile = new File("parentPath"+"/"+"ABC");
File newRenameFile = new File("parentPath"+"/"+"XYZ");

 if (mainFile.renameTo(newRenameFile) {
  // Success
 }
```

But in Android 11;

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
   List<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
     long mediaID = getFilePathToMediaID(mainFile.getAbsolutePath(), MainActivity.this);
     Uri  Uri_one = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external"), mediaID);
     // i  am getting this value in `uri_one = "content://media/external/images/media/22686";`
     uris.add(Uri_one);
     
     requestRenamePermission(MainActivity.this, uris);
 }
```

asking for writePermission

```
   private static final int EDIT_REQUEST_CODE = 222;
    
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private void requestRenamePermission(Context context, List<Uri> uri_one) {
        PendingIntent pi = MediaStore.createWriteRequest(context.getContentResolver(), uri_one);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(pi.getIntentSender(), EDIT_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
          case EDIT_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // after getting write permission on this mainFile i am again calling rename function.
                    
                    if (mainFile.renameTo(newRenameFile) {
                       // Success
                    }else{
                       // Failed to Rename - in Android 11
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to get WRITE Permission on this...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

where `22686` is media ID which i got from following function.

```
public static long getFilePathToMediaID(String songPath, Context context) {
    long id = 0;
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    String[] selectionArgs = {songPath};
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection + "=?", selectionArgs, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(idIndex));
        }
    }

    return id;
}
```

For rename I used `oldFile.renameTo(newFile)` function as we used till Android 10.

But this not helps me for rename. Your small guide can helps me a lot!!

Comment: @blackapps Please review my edited question and guide me on this

Comment: `For rename I used oldFile.renameTo(newFile)` Well that will not go as you have no file path but an uri.  You cannot use the File class for an uri.

Comment: @blackapps check now

Comment: Ok. But as said before:  you cannot use File.renameTo. Use the uri directly to update column .DISPLAY_NAME using MediaStore. Well DISPLAY_NAME is for a file. I never renamed a folder though. Further: you call it mainFile but you mean mainFolder or so. Quite confusing. And why are you talking about albums?

Comment: `"Failed to get WRITE Permission on this...!",` Wrong message. You got the permission but used it wrong.

Comment: @blackapps here i am renaming folders not files & check `onActivityResult()` function coz its just a msg while fail to get write permission. i am renaming folders on `Activity.RESULT_OK`.

Comment: No you do not fail to get write permission. You got it! You should use it in the right way. Which you dont. You fail to rename. You better toast that.

Comment: @blackapps yes i got permission; it goes inside Result_OK. Then renameTo Function executes. But it failed to rename in Andorid 11. and goes into Else part - ' Failed to Rename'

Comment: Well toast it!!

Comment: @blackapps IT DOES'NT MATTER. GUIDE IF YOU HAVE ANY SOLUTION FOR THIS

Comment: It does matter of course. And further i already told you what to do. So what do you want/need more?

Comment: what solution you provide? can you please point that again!?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this issue yet? I am facing the same problem and would appreciate any help.