# How to Move or Rename Image, Video File in Android 11 in Scoped Storage in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mediastore, scoped-storage

**i want to move and rename image file and this image file is not created my app so can i move or rename image file in android 11 in scoped storage.**

this is rename method for android api 11.

but it didn't work.

```
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "newFolder");

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File(model.getPicturePath());


        long mediaID = getFilePathToMediaID(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()).getAbsolutePath(), this);
        Uri utiOne =ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL),mediaID);

        String path = dir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+model.getPictureName();
        Toast.makeText(this, "" +model.getPicturePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
//        cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,".newFolder");
//        cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+File.separator+".newFolder");
        cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,path);
//        cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,model.getPictureId());

        getContentResolver().update(utiOne,cv,null);
```

Comment: How did that image file land in scoped storage of your app? And please mention full path.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68751501/album-folder-rename-not-working-in-android-11] same problem like this.

Comment: You did not give the info i asked for. Start with that.

Comment: now see question. this is move method . i want to move image one folder to another folder. so how can i do this. i have no idea about content value that i can put into content resolver.

Comment: For the third time: please give the info i asked in my first comment.

Comment: After Android API 29 android can't grant WRITE_EXTRANAL_STORAGE so ALL Image In Android 11 Is In Scoped Storage. i cant rename file like file.rename();

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this issue yet? I am facing the same problem and would appreciate any help.

Comment: @blackapps You're not making any sense. It never landed in the app's scoped storage to begin with. The image in question is placed in the public pictures directory, as the code shows.

Comment: `getFilePathToMediaID()` What is that? You might explain what your code is doing or what it should do. And you still did not give answer to my first comment: full path please.

Comment: If that code should rename an existing file then it is pretty unclear which file that would be (full path pleae) and if it is in a Pictures directory its pretty strange that you use mkdir() to create that directory. What sense does that have?

Comment: `so can i move or rename image file in android 11 in scoped storage.`  No question? No questionmark ? That image file is in Pictures directory if you wanna be precise and not confusing.

Comment: @blackapps I understood the question just fine. As will most other people. ‍♂️